# How can I hide my javascript source in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angular. I've done a lot of things with it. Built an internal website in my organization.

When I inspect regular web pages with chrome dev tools, I generally can't see any important javascript source files. But when I inspect my own angularjs web site, all of my controllers, directives and factories are there, exposed to everyone.

How can I hide them from users? Do I just have to minify them?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way. Even minified its readabble.

Comment: Anything on the client side is always visible.

Comment: You could try this http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Comment: When you say you cant see JS on other websites are you sure that the JS is not linked from a external source

Comment: That is a good question Qwertie. I'll look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can hide your script from client.

Answer (score 1):

You could obfuscate it a lot, making each function dependant on another, building a massive "web" of functions that all depend on each other, but that would also make the code really REALLY messy for yourself. The best thing you could do is just put a license in your script, using `/* */` and that will atleast prevent most buisnesses from stealing the code.

Comment: Also it would slow down page loading

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are downloaded to the client so there is not much you can do.

You can try to [obfuscate javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) but it's mostly a waste of time IMO

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. At best you can compress your JavaScript to make is less readable but at the end of the day if someone want's access to your code they can get it. That said, this is true for most programming language now a days. It's fairly easy to get the code for apps written in Java, C#, VB, and Managed C++.