# How to hide javascript from being seen on the inspect element

Tags: javascript

Is there any efficient way or plugin to include in order to hide javascript from being seen on the inspect element?

Comment: You cant hide that, but you can minify that,so it will be unreadable.

Comment: No. But you can use tools like webpack or grunt, you can make it less readable

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client (in this case), so you will have to send it to the client/browser in order to run it there. If you send something to the client, they can see it. Security through obscurity, in this case, is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: You cant hide your code, but you can make it less readable by obfuscate, minify...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide my javascript source in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280732/how-can-i-hide-my-javascript-source-in-browser)

Comment: Please use the search next time, this has been asked hundreds of times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+javascript+source

Answer (score 1):

One word answer: no.

It is a badly created site if the site's security depends on "hiding" the source code. Try uglifying your code if you really don't want others seeing it, but it can always be reverse-engineered.

Comment: This could have been a comment, in my POV

Comment: @Rajesh But is it a valid answer?

Comment: Its a valid answer. Thats why I added *in my POV*. But the reason I commented was, its a fairly basic question and you can find answer on google. There is even a dupe, so we should rather look for such posts and close it. Since you know the solution, you are more likely to get a better dupe then OP. But this all is again my POV.